# Angularjs ng-repeat stylization depending on previous value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having some data(objects in massive inside main massive. Data looks like

```
masses=[
[
  {param1:150, param2:20, param3:"one"},
  {param1:150, param2:21, param3:"one"},
  {param1:150, param2:22, param3:"one"},
  {param1:150, param2:23, param3:"one"},
  {param1:100, param2:24, param3:"one"}
],
[
  {param1:100, param2:26, param3:"one"}
],
[
  {param1:100, param2:26, param3:"two"},
  {param1:150, param2:26, param3:"two"},
  {param1:100, param2:26, param3:"three"}
]
```

];

[image]

Is that any simple way to make view looks like this

[image]

So, if in previous object the same property has the same value, this will displays with, for example, `opacity:0,4;`?

https://plnkr.co/edit/g73tRszeVmxfGDbpbDEv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your model, flag the objects that have that condition. Then, while looping over the objects in the ng-repeat, use ng-class to apply specific CSS classes.

ng-class: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass